# Lectura de Fichero Java

Tags: java

quisiera saber como almacenar las lineas de un fichero en una variable. Mi codigo permite leer el fichero y las lineas las almaceno en una variable llamada linea pero cuando accedo a esta variable desde otra clase de da null, como si nunca se hubiera almacenado nada.

```
public void cargarFichero () throws IOException {
        try {
            entrada = new BufferedReader(new FileReader ("./src/estudiante.txt"));
            lineas = entrada.readLine();
            while(lineas!=null){
    
                lineas=entrada.readLine();
                
            }
            
        }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
```

este es mi codigo, lee correctamente el fichero txt.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como se puede ver en la imagen carga perfectamente lo que hay en el fichero txt pero cuando quiero acceder a esa informacion almacenada en linea me sale null
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Existe la forma de almacenar el contenido de un fichero en una variable para asi ser utilizada por otra clase?

Comment: Usa un Arraylist  y has uso de su método add()

Comment: Claro que da null, si no diese `null` tu código nunca saldría del bucle para empezar. Lo que necesitas es pensar de manera lógica y revisar lo que has programado. Además, si quieres almacenar todas las líneas, no te sirve un único string... necesitas un array, una lista, algún tipo de colección! (o un string donde vas *concatenando* todas las líneas).

Answer (score -1):

Según la [documentación](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#:%7E:text=A%20String%20containing%20the%20contents%20of%20the%20line%2C%20not%20including%20any%20line%2Dtermination%20characters%2C%20or%20null%20if%20the%20end%20of%20the%20stream%20has%20been%20reached) oficial de Java el método `readLine` solo devolverá `null` en caso de que el documento haya sido completamente leído.

En tu caso tienes un ciclo que específicamente lo que hace es llamar a este método hasta que devuelva `null` por ende es normal que te devuelva `null`.

En tu caso puedes utilizar el método `concat` de la clase `String`. También puedes utilizar un `List<String>` o el método `readAllLines`. Espero esto pueda ayudarte.